# Asp.net core, basic problems i dont understand

Tags: asp.net, caching, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

**First Problem:**

```
services.AddMemoryCache();  // in Startup config
public class AController
{
public AController(IMemoryCache cacheA) { }
}

public class BController
{
public BController(IMemoryCache cacheB) { }
}
```

problem is that cacheA is the same as cacheB

i'd like to have private API (cluster connections) and public API (exposed to frontend)
how to separate them while keeping it all DI pattern friendly?

**Second problem;**

i want to have a service that requests some external webserver via HTTP
and its results would be cached in that service, also stored in DB
so we first query localCache then query DB then query external server

results from that service would be used in Controllers and sent to frontend

How to implement such thing with all the fancy  asp.netcore patterns?
cache must be the ONE(singleton) so we dont waste DB requests

? adding such Service as  services.SCOPED<> but then how to keep it its cache same for every instance (some singleton DI? or static MemoryCache instance?)
i have no idea, no damn idea begging for help

in node.js i would have done it all in a couple of minutes, but its Microsoft hey

Comment: One look at the source would have answered all of your questions: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/efbbdc5e0a8c8a664ea34cd41220d084b6906f57/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L76-L86

Comment: lol, thats a good one, it would be a good feature if VS's (Peek Definition - Alt F12) could acually show you the source

Answer (score 1):

Define two cache interfaces:

```
public interface IPrivateMemoryCache: IMemoryCache
{
}

public interface IPublicMemoryCache: IMemoryCache
{
}

public class AController
{
    public AController(IPrivateMemoryCache cacheA) { }
}

public class BController
{
    public BController(IPublicMemoryCache cacheB) { }
}
```

Now you can define different instantiation rules for your IoC container.

Comment: Doing this only makes sense when both interfaces define a different contract, or in other words, when having one `IMemoryCache` interface would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Don't think you are fully getting the LSP.  It not only has to do with the data types and names of the data members but also *behavioral* subtyping (which explains, for example. the use of [marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) all of which have identical members).  If the design calls for an independent private and public cache, they are logically different.

Comment: I think I understand LSP just fine :) and yes you are right it is all about behavior. The question here is, do those implementations behave differently from the perspective of the consumer or not.

Comment: It sounds like it is a requirement that items created in the private cache do not impact the storage space of the public cache, and vice versa, so yes, there is a distinct behavior required.  I imagine the size and lifespan of the two caches may be configured independently as well.  OTOH, can you think of any alternatives to using two interfaces?